# A sequence that is convergent in $\ell^\infty$ but not in $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I saw a few sequences $(x_n)_n$ such that $(x_n)_n$ is convergent with respect to $(\ell^1, d_\infty)$ but not convergent with respect to $(\ell^1, d_2)$. Here, $$\ell^1 = \left\{(a_n)_n: \sum_{i=0}^\infty |a_i| <\infty\right\}$$
and $d_2$ and $d_\infty$ are defined by $$d_2((a_n)_n,(b_n)_n) = {\biggl(\sum_{i=0}^\infty |a_i-b_i|^2\biggr)}^{1/2}$$

$$d_\infty((a_n)_n,(b_n)_n) = \sup_i |a_i-b_i|$$

One of the examples is $$x_n = \biggl(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{1}{n},0,0,0,\ldots\biggr)  $$
where $1/n$ appears $n^3$ times. Then, $x_n$ converges to $x = (0,0,0,\ldots)$ with respect to $d_\infty$ but does not converge to $x = (0,0,0,\ldots)$ with respect to $d_2$. I do understand why it converges with respect to $d_\infty$ but does not converge with respect to $d_2$. But what I don't understand is whether $x_n\in \ell^1$ for all $n$. I see that if I pick an arbitrary $n$, then $x_n\in \ell^1$ since $\sum_{i=0}^\infty|x_i| = \frac{1}{n}\cdot n^3 = n^2$ is finite. But because I am dealing with a sequence when I think about $n\to \infty$ situation I think $\sum_{i=0}^\infty|x_i| = \frac{1}{n}\cdot n^3 = n^2$ tends to $\infty$. Therefore, $x_n \notin \ell^1$ as $n\to \infty$. I know I am wrong about $x_n \notin \ell^1$ but I don't know where I am wrong. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: It is precisely the point that each *individual* $x_i$ lies in $\ell^1$ but that the limit in the sense of $d_2$ does not lie in $\ell^1$. Maybe you should reflect on the statement "$x_n\not\in\ell_1$ as $n\to\infty$" (this statement has no formal meaning, as $n\to\infty$ depends on the norm)

Answer (score 2):

When you say $x_n \in \ell^{1}$  for each $n$ you fix $n$ and prove that $x_n \in \ell^{1}$. The limit as $n \to \infty$ is not at all involved in this statement.

Answer (score 1):

In all three norms we have that **if** $(x_n)_n \to x$ (in the norm, which is the same as $\|x_n - x\| \to 0$), **then** $(x_n)_m \to x_m$ (as $ n \to \infty$, in $\Bbb R$) for each fixed coordinate $m$.

This means that if the $x_n$ are as defined, the only candidate for the limit of $(x_n)$ in any norm is $\underline{0}=(0,0,0,0,\ldots)$

All individual vectors $(x_n)$ lie in $\ell^\infty, \ell^1, \ell^2$ because they have finitely many terms that are non-zero, so the $\sup$ or their sum of sum of squares is well-defined. But to check that $x_n \to \underline{0}$ in a norm (it's the only possible candidate limit, by the first remark!) we have to check whether $\|x_n -x\| \to 0$ in the norm we're considering.

And $\|x_n\|_\infty  = \frac{1}{n}$ so in $\ell^\infty$ we have convergence.

$\|x_n\|_2 = \sqrt{n^3 \times \frac{1}{n^2}} = \sqrt{n}$

and $\|x_n\|^1 = n^3 \times \frac{1}{n}= n^2$ so we don't have convergence in those norms.

Answer (score 0):

So what if $n\rightarrow \infty$? For fixed $n$, $\sum^{\infty}_{I=1}|x_i|$ $=$ $n^2$ $<\infty$.  You don't care what happens if $n$ tends to infinity.